# Is there a way to open a shared read only connection to a shared Access database using ADO?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ado

I have developed a system in which a group of users (appr 50 people right now) registers data and view registered data continously. The system stores data in an Access database, and I currently use the connection mode adModeShareDenyNone for all users in order for the database to never lock up the access to the database.

However it has been requested that I develop a simple Excel worksheet acting as an interface where a user can write an sql select statement and then retrieve data to the sheet according to this (via VBA). This is very simple and I have created such, however I want it to prevent the execution of manipulative statements (insert, update, delete), that is, act as a read-only system.

However I can't seem to find a way to do this without locking up the database for other user too, which is a no go, since the database is in constant use by multiple users. Is there a way to do what I want? I thought of other connection modes, but they all (besides adModeShareDenyNone) seem to apply some sort of locking.

Comment: To clarify, the user types their own SQL statement? If so, can you not just validate/restrict the string via VBA before allowing it to be executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `adModeRead`? That indicates read-only permissions and no share.

Comment: +1 Absolutely, a read_only connection is the answer, this should also avoid any locking issues